# perl replacing "or die" with timeout and try again

Tags: perl, sockets, networking

Could someone help me modify this line?

```
$MySocket=new IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerPort=>$port,Proto=>'tcp',PeerAddr=>$IP) or die $E;
```

I need to change it so that if it fails, time out for 10 seconds and try again 3 times or die.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
my $fails = 0;
while (!($MySocket=new IO::Socket::INET->new(
        PeerPort=>$port,Proto=>'tcp',PeerAddr=>$IP))) {
    die ($E) if ++$fails ==  3;  
    sleep(10);
}
```